# Image Resampling Bicubic Interpolation Java

Tags: interpolation, bicubic

I have resized image but its quality is low. i heard of bicubic interpolation but i cant get any implementation code. Here is my code:

```
private static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) 
{ 
    int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
    int type = image.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : image.getType();
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);

    //g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.scale((double)width/w,(double)height/h);
    g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resizedImage; 
}
```

I want to get the best quality after upsampling and downsampling.

Answer (score 1):

Bicubic interpolation and other interpolation schemes are needed only when you need to resize by some non-integer scale factor. What you're probably missing is that you need to *filter* your image prior to *downsampling* (when shrinking) or filter after *upsampling* (when expanding) to avoid aliasing artefacts, which is an entirely different problem. This applies to both integer and non-integer scale factors.

Comment: What algorithm is used when enlarging by an integer factor? I don't see how interpolation is unnecessary.

Comment: @erickson: well filtering and interpolation are somewhat interchangeable terms in this context - e.g. by low-pass filtering after upsampling you effectively interpolate the inserted zero samples.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!